# How to override a library function in python that is not in __all__?

Tags: python, overriding, networkx

I would like to override a function in NetworkX. More precisely in the file [geometric.py](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/main/networkx/generators/geometric.py) I'd like to override the function `geometric_edges`. My naïve attempt looks as follows

```
import networkx as nx

def geometric_edges_new(G, radius, p):
    # tried it with the name "geometric_edges" and with the changed name both doesn't work
    return []

...
nx.generators.geometric.geometric_edges = geometric_edges_new
return nx.random_geometric_graph(number, radius, pos=pos)
```

This attempt does not work (meaning, the function provided in the given file is still executed instead of my own).

Comment: "does not work" is not very helpful. What does happen?

Comment: after you run `import networkx as nx` the original function has already been imported as well as all the tertiary functions that use that, so what you are doing here won't work

Comment: @gold_cy could you tell me how I can do it that it works? Basically that is the reason I created this question

Comment: why is this question being voted to be closed? it is clear to me what OP wants

Comment: @MadPhysicist why was this voted to be closed, it is clear what OP wants. This sort of behavior discourages new users from participating.

Comment: @gold_cy. "Participating" is not the bar we are trying to set here. My first comment addressed exactly the problem I have with the question. We want questions that are clearly written according to [ask]. "It's broken, please fix" is not a valid question because a solution may help OP in the immediate sense, but does nothing for future visitors to the site, which is what this Q&A is about.

Comment: OP is asking how to override a function which has not been exported under `__all__` within that file. They demonstrate their attempt and state that their approach does not work. What more can OP do? The problem has been stated clearly and they have shown what they tried. Also OP does not say "it's broken, please fix". The title articulates clearly what the issue is.

Comment: I really don't know how to change this question - maybe just repost it and hope for better luck?

Comment: @baxbear Have you taken  a look at [`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html)? I realize you are not unit testing, but you could still use that in this situation.

Comment: @SethMMorton What lets you assume I am not unit testing? How did you get to this assumption. My problem is that I don't know how to override a library function that is not in `__all__` and therefore I created this example. I know that my approach doesn't work but I couldn't find a better one yet.

Comment: @baxbear Whoa - I just meant that it looks like the code you posted is not intended to be a test, not that you were not unit testing in general. Anyway, I genuinely believe that using unittest.mock is the solution to your problem, sorry you felt like I attacked you... I would have posted it as an answer if the question were not closed.

Comment: @SethMMorton No problem, even if I wouldn't mind, maybe you are right, maybe not - as long as you don't tell me I'm fat and ugly or something and the criticism stays on a professional level I am fine with it. I am not yet sure I understand exactly to which point you are guiding me with your answer but I will have to look into it tomorrow it is already after midnight here.

Comment: I am suggesting you do `unittest.mock.patch("nx.generators.geometric.geometric_edges", geometric_edges_new)`. You can use it in a context manager if you only want to patch for the duration of that call to `nx.random_geometric_graph`.